# How to access context of render_to_string in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this code from Django-registration app.

```
  def send_activation_email(self, email):   
    email = email   
    ctx_dict = { 'activation_key' : self.activation_key,
         'expiration_days': settings.ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS,
                                                            }

    subject = render_to_string('activation_email_subject.txt', ctx_dict)
    subject = ''.join(subject.splitlines())
    message = render_to_string('activation_email.txt', ctx_dict)

    send_mail(subject, message, 'gccFishing.com', [email],  fail_silently = False)
```

Inside `activation_email.txt` is this: this is the body

The output email to console is this:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: this is the subject
From: gccFishing.com
To: ipad@ap.com
Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2013 20:39:04 -0000
Message-ID: <20130901203904.3048.2540@hammad-P5QL-E>

this is the body
```

1. Where does the `ctx_dict` get stored?
2. How can I access `ctx_dict` to check whether the activation key has been sent or no?
3. How to get back `ctx_dict`  to the server once the client clicks a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.The `ctx_dict` won't be stored anywhere - it is passed to the template renderer to make `activation_key` and `expiration_days` available to your template. For example a better email template would be -

`Thanks for registering, you have {{expiration_days}} to activate your account at {% url 'registration_activate' activation_key %}`

2.You can't access `ctx_dict` anywhere other than your template (and even then you are accessing it indirectly).  You can however query the database.  A RegistrationProfile is created for anyone who has registered and the email is sent at this time.  You can test if they are activated by either querying the `User.is_active` field or testing if `RegistrationProfile.activation == Registration.ACTIVATED` is true.

3.Again you don't.  You query the database for the information.

As a casual observation it seems like you are using django-registration incorrectly to need this information.  The app has a number of views and a urlconf already setup to manage the entire registration process, you only need to supply the templates, as per [the docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) for a standard registration setup.

Comment: Thanks and you're right, I'm not using django-registration completely, just the registration part. I have my own custom user. I have removed the registration profile part from django-registration. In your answer above, what if registration_activate was a method of a User class? and that it should be called with a user object, like this user.registration_activate. How would this be done from the template? any ideas?

Comment: Well to call a function from your template, you would simply use `.` notation eg. `user.registration_activate`.  To use that though you will need to add you `User` object to the template context.